# Python f-string equivalent in R?

Tags: r

Does R have an equivalent of the Python f-string?
Like this example in Python:

```
name = "Eric"
age = 42
f"Hello, {name}. You are {age}."
```

I know about `paste` and `paste0`, but they require you to separate the different elements with commas. I could not find anything about it while searching the Internet.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can use [`glue`](https://github.com/tidyverse/glue):

```
library(glue)
name <- "Eric"
age <- 42
glue('Hello, {name}. You are {age}.')
#> Hello, Eric. You are 42.
```

Answer (score 24):

[sprintf](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/sprintf) is the most direct option in R's standard library, so you don't need to install any other packages or libraries since it's just a wrapper for the underlying C function. However, I will admit the syntax is a bit trickier if you aren't used to it.

```
name <- "Eric"
age <- 42
sprintf("Hello, %s. You are %s.", name, age)
```

Result:
`[1] "Hello, Eric. You are 42."`

If you really don't like the syntax there, you can try [paste0](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/paste) to get the same result.

```
name <- "Eric"
age <- 42
paste0("Hello, ", name, ". You are ", age, ".")
```

Answer (score 6):

The gsubfn package allows you to preface any function with `fn$` in which case character arguments will support perl-style string interpolation using backticks or $ sign (and formula notation can be used for function arguments).

```
library(gsubfn)
name <- "Eric"
age <- 42
fn$plot(0, main = "Hello, `name`. You are `age`.")
```

The part within backticks can be an R expression:

```
fn$identity("Hello, `name`. You are `age+1`.")
## [1] "Hello, Eric. You are 43."
```

It also supports $ notation if the end of the variable name can be inferred from the string.  That is not the case in the above since dot is valid in a variable name but this would work:

```
fn$c("Hello $name")
## [1] "Hello Eric"
```

One can also use gsubfn from the same package.  This looks for a string surrounded by brace brackets and then substitutes the variable name in it for its contents.

```
gsubfn("{(.*?)}", get, "Hello, {name}. You are {age}.")
## [1] "Hello, Eric. You are 42."
```

or a list can be provided as the second argument

```
L <- list(name = "Eric", age = 42)
gsubfn("{(.*?)}", L, "Hello, {name}. You are {age}.")
## [1] "Hello, Eric. You are 42."
```

This would also work using the same list.  It avoids the use of {...} and would work as long as name and age do not appear elsewhere in the string.  It looks up words, i.e. substrings made up of word characters, in the list.

```
gsubfn("\\w+", L, "Hello, name. You are age.")
## [1] "Hello, Eric. You are 42."
```